# Asymptotic of $\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}a_n$ where $\exp(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha\operatorname{rad}(n)n^{-s})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^s}$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, dirichlet-series

Yesterday I tried to study the article [1] in wich were showed incredible expressions related to Dirichlet series. In the same way I wondered about next question.

We denote for integers $m>1$ the product of its distinct prime numbers dividing $m$ as $$\operatorname{rad}(m)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid m\\p\text{ prime}}}p,$$
with the definition $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$ (see it you want the Wikipedia [*Radical of an integer,*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) that is the famous multiplicative function in the statement of the abc conjecture.

I know approximations (I say from several posts of Mathematics Stack Exchange) for the corresponding Dirichlet series that I denote as
$$\mathcal{D}_{\text{rad}}(s):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\operatorname{rad}(n)}{n^s}\tag{1}$$

for $\Re s>1$, where $s$ is the complex variable.

> **Problem.** In a similar way than [1], we consider $\alpha$ a non-zero complex constant, and we define the sequence $a_n$ as $$\exp\left(\alpha\cdot\mathcal{D}_{\text{rad}}(s)\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^s},$$
>   in $\Re s>1$. Is it possible to get the a formula for the asymptotic behaviour of the sequence $$\sum_{1\leq n\leq x}a_n$$
>   as $x\to\infty$? What is the strategy/hinsts in this problem? **Many thanks.**

I hope that my question is answerable and interesting. I don't know if this question is in the literature.

### References:

[1] R. Balasubramanian and K. RamaChandra, *Some Problems of Analytic Number Theory - V*, from Diophantine Equations, Editor: N. Saradha, Tata Institute of Fundamental Research, Narosa Publishing House (2008).

Comment: Since your Dirichlet series acts somewhat like $\zeta(s-1)$ near its pole at $s=2$, I would try to find out what is known about $\exp(\zeta(s)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \big( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \tau_k(n)/n! \big) n^{-s}$.

Comment: @GregMartin His Dirichlet series is $F(s)=\exp(\alpha \zeta(s-1)) G(s)$ where $G$ converges absolutely for $\Re(s) > 1$. The problem is that $\zeta(s) = O(\frac{\log t}{\log \log t})$ is known only on $\Re(s) = 1$ not to the left where we only have $O(\log^5 t)$ so exponentiating give $F(s) = O(s^{5|\alpha|})$ which means we can apply the Tauberian theorems only to $\sum_{n \le x} (x-n)^k a_n, k \ge \lceil 5|\alpha| \rceil$. Plus even under the Tauberian theorems we'll obtain $\sim Res(F(s) \frac{x^{s+k}}{s^k},s=2)= \sum_{m \ge 0} x^{2+k} (\log x)^m c_m$ whose asymptotic is unclear.

Comment: Many thanks @GregMartin feel free to add your approach.

Comment: Many thanks for your attention, feel free to add your remarks, sure that it is a very good answer for all us @reuns